# js sort with async function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I use an custom function to sort a collection and it works fine. However, if I add an asynchronous call inside it stops working and I can't figure out why.

Here's the working verion:

```
async _sort(order, grouping) {
  await this._getCollection();

  this._collection.sort(function (x, y) {
    var jsonX = JSON.parse(x);
    var jsonY = JSON.parse(y);

    /*
     * Groupings are always sorted alphabetically no mat-
     * ter the order, except for date...
     */
    if (!((grouping === null) || (grouping === CollectionViewBuilder.DATE()))) {
      var groupX = jsonX[grouping];
      var groupY = jsonY[grouping];

      if (!(groupX === groupY)) {
        return groupX.localeCompare(groupY);
      }
    }

    /*
     * ...then items are sorted chronologically, depen-
     * ding on the order.
     */
    var dateX = Date.parse(jsonX.date);
    var dateY = Date.parse(jsonY.date);
    return (order === CollectionViewBuilder.DESC() ? dateY - dateX : dateX - dateY);
  });
}
```

And here is what I want to do:

```
async _sort(order, grouping) {
  await this._getCollection();

  async function sortGroupingOrder (x, y) {
    var jsonX = JSON.parse(x);
    var jsonY = JSON.parse(y);

    /*
     * Groupings are always sorted alphabetically no mat-
     * ter the order, except for date...
     */
    if (!((grouping === null) || (grouping === CollectionViewBuilder.DATE()))) {
      var groupX = await this._pageBuilder.translator.getTranslatedWord(jsonX[grouping]);
      var groupY = await this._pageBuilder.translator.getTranslatedWord(jsonY[grouping]);

      if (!(groupX === groupY)) {
        return groupX.localeCompare(groupY);
      }
    }

    /*
     * ...then items are sorted chronologically, depen-
     * ding on the order.
     */
    var dateX = Date.parse(jsonX.date);
    var dateY = Date.parse(jsonY.date);
    return (order === CollectionViewBuilder.DESC() ? dateY - dateX : dateX - dateY);
  }

  this._collection.sort(sortGroupingOrder.bind(this));
}
```

I also did a jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/GaetanL/qh34rwuv/8/

EDIT: I looked for the answer provided by qxg and put my asynchronous treatment outside the sort function and it worked.

Comment: It explains a lot, thanks! I edited my question 'cause now I have another problem could you have a look?

Comment: This code is **too large and too complex**, please create & show a simplified version of it.